# Query taking long time to insert data in sql server express

Tags: sql-server

I have strange scenario in which if I create database using SQL Server 2008 Express (database compatibility level SQL Server 2008) and perform insert using xml datatype, it executes indefinitely, but when  same query is executed on database with compatibility level SQL Server 2005 it runs fine and executes in less than one minute.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the table structure in question, the XML you're inserting, the code you're using to insert?? Otherwise it's a guessing game at best.......

Comment: Problem is infact bug in 2008 server
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/562092/an-insert-statement-using-xml-nodes-is-very-very-very-slow-in-sql2008-sp1
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957205/
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940943/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has whitepapers about changes between SQL2005 and 2008.  I would look there for any related breaking changes.  If you expect to get an adequate answer on this site I would suggest posting code.